# CSV file that lists all student answers to the problem

Tags: openedx

As I followed the steps to download CSV of problem responses for a problem, It says “The problem responses report is being created. To view the status of the report, see Pending Tasks below.”
But, I am not seeing any pending tasks nor the files are being generated. Can’t see the generated file even after refreshing.
But, I can generate other CSV files for example, Problem Grade Report.
The issue is only for the problem response report.

PS: When I checked Admin, I could see that the request was failed with this error:

```
{"exception": "AssertionError", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n File \"/openedx/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py\", line 240, in trace_task\n R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)\n File \"/openedx/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py\", line 438, in __protected_call__\n return self.run(*args, **kwargs)\n File \"/openedx/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/instructor_task/tasks.py\", line 171, in calculate_problem_responses_csv\n return run_main_task(entry_id, task_fn, action_name)\n File \"/openedx/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/instructor_task/tasks_helper/runner.py\", line 111, in run_main_task\n task_progress = task_fcn(entry_id, course_id, task_input, action_name)\n File \"/openedx/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/instructor_task/tasks_helper/grades.py\", line 737, in generate\n usage_key_str=problem_location\n File \"/openedx/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/instructor_task/tasks_helper/grades.py\", line 674, ...", "message": ""}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having much tries I was able to figure out my issue was caused because one operation which is not quite preferable by Open Edx. It is changing correct answer of a problem after few students submitting their responses. I was able to get their grades calculated based on new answers by using the Re-score option but unable to generate this report. 
I will update here if I get a solution.